# My nested list always adds an empty string

Tags: python

For some reason, it keeps adding an empty ' ' in the nested list.

This is how the results are printed out:

```
[['Sara', '37', '32', '47', ''], ['Johan', '44', '29', '34', ''], ['Kalle', '33', '34', '34', ''], ['Oskar', '23', '47', '45', '']]
```

I have tried what is in this article but it doesn't work. Not sure where the fault is.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-empty-strings-from-list-of-strings/

```
def results_from_file(file_name):
    file_exist()
    
    my_file = open(file_name, "r")
    data = my_file.read().split("\n")
    
    results = []
    
    for row in data:
        results.append(row.split(";"))
    
    return results
```

Comment: Your lines probably all end in `;`.

Comment: They do. Is there a way to fix that? @Aplet123

Comment: `row.rstrip(";").split(";")`

Comment: I'm confused where that would be implemented or what it would replace @Aplet123

Comment: You'd replace the `row.split(";")` with that.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked <3  Still pretty new to python just trying figure it out step by step xD @Aplet123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aplet123 said:

> Your lines probably all end in `;`

Try this to fix:

replace

```py
data = my_file.read().split("\n")
```

to

```py
data = my_file.read().replace(';\n','\n').split("\n")
```